# Can Coldfusion ORM access an Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, orm, coldfusion, triggers, sequence

I have ORM setup and working with Oracle on an existing database and have been able to get inserts to work when I access the sequence but because triggers were used in the original application the sequence skips a number.

Is there a way to get ORM to use the trigger?

Disabling the trigger is not an option since it is used by the existing app and cannot be disabled during migration.

```
component persistent="true" table="table_name"  schema="schema_name" { 
   property name="table_id" column="table_id" fieldtype="id" generator="sequence" sequence="schema_name.sequence_name";
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers are not accessible program units.  The only way to "call" a trigger is to execute the appropriate DML against the owning table.

There are two possible resolutions to your problem.

1. **Rewrite the trigger**.  You say another application still needs the trigger to populate the ID, but you could change the trigger's logic with a conditional....

   ```
   if :new.id is null  then
        :new.id := whatever_seq.nextval;  --11g syntax for brevity
   end if;
   ```

   This will populate the ID when the other application insert into the table but won't overwrite your value.
2. **Stop worrying**.  Sequences are merely generators of unique identifiers.  The numbers ascend but it really doesn't matter if there are gaps.  Unless you are handling *billions* of rows it is extremely unlikely your sequence will run out of numbers before your applications get retired.

Comment: 2: I considered this but some of our departments like consecutive numbers. 

1: This worked but I also had to add 
    if :new.id='' then

and dropped the default column value since both of these should take care of this. I had to use the following syntax for the sequence on our server instead of the 11g syntax. 

    select schema.table.nextval into  :new.id from dual;

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the DB normally assigns an ID, using an insert trigger? That would explain why you're skipping a number. You could try generator="select" which will get hibernate to read the ID back after the insert has occurred (and the trigger has been fired). It's there to handle exactly the situation I think you're describing.

Comment: I like this solution but I get the following error

null id in comparables entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Comment: Reading up on this, it looks like the generator="select" makes hibernate run the insert, then try to select the row back, using the other fields in the object. This may not be possible in CF's implementation of Hibernate or in your object if the other fields aren't unique. I think APC's solution is best if you have scope to modify the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the research. That sounds like a reasonable explanation since the test inserts were mostly empty fields except one other value. Your solution would have been easier to implement but fortunately I do have access to modify the triggers it is just more of a pain since I have to have the DBA move them to production for me.